# How to pass a function with arguments, to a function, in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given this definition...

```
function initialize(lat, lng)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

How do I call arguments to the initialize function in this call?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I wanna do something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(58,18));
```

Call 1 works even without any arguments passed to it, but it's something similar to call 2 I want to accomplish.

Sorry, this is probably something quite easy, I'm new to javascript... (but I've googled for quite some time now)

Edit:

Grrr, found it, swear I already tried it, must have had a type or smoething!

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){initialize(1,2);});
```

Comment: Research about callbacks in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    push.call(arguments, 58);
    push.call(arguments, 18);
    initialize.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

not quite, initialize doesn't have the signature of a DomListener, better to do:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    initialize.call(this, 58, 18);
});
```

the first pushes the two arguments to the special [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) pseudo-array (hence the need for [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)) and then invokes initialize in the context of the listener's context, [applying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the arguments from the current function on the arguments of the called function (initialize).

The second calls initialize in the context of the listener. If you don't need the context, you can simply do:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    initialize(58, 18);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the things that [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) can achieve, remember which `this` you want too, though.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(
    window,
    'load',
    initialize.bind(null, 58, 18)
);
```

The above will invoke `initialised` with `this` set to `window` and first two params `58`, `18`. It might be easier to understand in this example

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    console.log(this, a, b, c);
}
var foobar = foo.bind(null, 1, 2);
foobar('bar');
// window, 1, 2, "bar"
```